# In Bash, can a "mv-for loop" be done on one line?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I frequently require to type

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
for i in files-*
do
    mv $i ${i/files/items}
done
```

Can this be done simpler?

Answer (score 2):

In one line: yes. Simpler: probably not.

```
for i in files-*; do mv "$i" "${i/files/items}"; done
```

If you need something like this frequently, you could encapsulate it in a function and just call that function. Or define some sort of template/text block/macro in your preferred editor.

Comment: Also, unless you are *certain* the file names don't contain spaces, newlines, etc., you should quote both `$i` and `${i/files/items}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `perl` installed, you can use `rename`:

```
rename 's/files/items/' files-*
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't get a lot shorter than what Ansgar already suggested.  However, you can save some typing via a couple of mechanisms:

#### Bash command history

Use bash's [command history](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-bash-command-line-history/) to recall the command.  Not exactly hi-tech, but this cann save you a lot of typing, and you don't have to save/alter whatsoever on your system.

#### A script file

Put the command in a script file you save somewhere in your path.

```
 #/bin/bash
 for i in files-*; do 
     mv $i ${i/files/items} 
 done
```

In this case I'd leave the multiple lines intact to optimize readabilty

#### Alias

Add an [alias](http://www.ss64.com/bash/alias.html) for the command to your .bashrc file

```
 alias movem='for i in files-*; do mv $i ${i/files/items}; done'
```

Once you've done that, just typing the alias will allow you to run the command.  One advantage of this is that you don't have to create a script file.

ps: `/usr/bin/bash` ??? What system are you using?

Comment: @TMOTTM Okay, you'll see that in my example I already used `/bin/bash` because on most non stone age systems bash lives there.